# PyCharm does not recognized a module in the project

Tags: python, pycharm

I ran in the following problem:
I created a project in Pycharm and my PyCharm does not recognized a modules from the packages.

I use Python 3.6

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should add a project interpreter. Open project settings and add an interpreter.

Comment: Check that the sources root is IndeedPOM (the folder should be blue if it is the case). You can right click on the folder and go to "Mark directory as" to set this up. Then, try to use the full path w.r.t. the root i.e., `from pages.base_page import func1, func2, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following steps:

1. Go to `File->Settings` (it'll open a window). In the right box, go to `Project->Project structure`. In the left click in `+ add content root` and pick the folder module you'd like to add. After that, mark this folder as `Source`

You're gonna see something like that:
[image]

2. In this same window, go to `Project Interpreter`. In the top right click in the `gear icon` and `show all`. In the right, there are some icons, click in the last one `show paths for the selected interpreted`. Now, click on the `plus icon` and insert the path for your project.

This screen looks like that:
[image]